# In SQL (maybe python?), how to find grouping differences between prior months?

Tags: sql, grouping, aggregate-functions, lag, difference

The following query:

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT
    PaymentDate, 
    GroupNumber
FROM DBO
GROUP BY PaymentDate, GroupNumber
)
SELECT 
    PaymentDate, 
    MONTH(PaymentDate) AS Payment_Month,
    COUNT(DISTINCT GroupNumber) AS GP_CNT,
    GroupNumber
INTO #Groupings
FROM CTE
GROUP BY PaymentDate, GroupNumber WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY PaymentDate, GroupNumber

SELECT * FROM #Groupings
```

Gives the following output:

| PaymentDate | Payment_month | GP_cnt | GroupNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 2 | 1111 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 2 | 1112 |
| 2022-02-01 | 2 | 4 | 2221 |
| 2022-02-01 | 2 | 4 | 2222 |
| 2022-02-01 | 2 | 4 | 2223 |
| 2022-02-01 | 2 | 4 | 2224 |
| 2022-03-01 | 3 | 4 | *2221* |
| 2022-03-01 | 3 | 4 | *2222* |
| 2022-03-01 | 3 | 4 | **3333** |
| 2022-03-01 | 3 | 4 | **3334** |

I seek to find the list of Group numbers from the present month that are not present from the prior month, aka new groups that have been added to the present month. I am thinking about starting with the Lag function but I am not sure where to go. Would this solution be easier to solve in Python? Would it be better to generate a CSV of the output above and use pandas? Thank you!

Desired Result/Output:

```
| GroupNumber |
|-------------|
| 3333        |
| 3334        |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check your table on itself to look for groups not existing in previous months

```
SELECT * 
FROM #Groupings AS G
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 'X' X
    FROM #Groupings AS GG
    WHERE GG.GroupNumber = G.GroupNumber
    AND GG.Payment_month < G.Payment_month
)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! I am trying to understand the logic now. The "Select 'X' X" is just selecting rows from GG?

Comment: The EXISTS statement evaluates only the number of rows, regardless of the columns returned in the internal query. So instead of selecting * or a table column, I prefer to use a constant.